# Issue on Targeting Dynamic Content in an Exiting <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/1rnf0jfr/1/) and let me know why I am not able to apply CSS rules to `.popover` class?

As you can see I already tried the

```
$("#pop").find('.popover').css("background-color", "red");
$("#pop").closest(".popover").css("background-color", "red");
```

but neither of `.find()` or `.closest()` are working here!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is executed on DOM ready. JavaScript is event-based, you should listen to the events. Also none of your methods can select the target element since the element is the next sibling of the `#pop` element:

```
$("#pop").on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    $(this).next('.popover').css({
        "background-color": "red"
    });
});
```